# loading a html page with js

Tags: javascript

Is it **possible** to load for a html page and then when its finished loading all elements including pictures it will then move on to that page?

for example the user starts at page1 and then page2 starts to load and then when page2 is finished loading it goes into page2? is this possible with only javascript or **javascript libraries**?

also page2 has like let say 20 pictures on it, so i want to load all of those pictures and the n display page2?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please limit you question to one desired scenario. Describe it as accurate and simple as possible, also show what you have done so far (if any).

Comment: I think you might want to reconsider your page design or make sure the image you are presenting are not to big (in MB's). What you asking for now seems a bit weird.

Comment: @Petr, it looks like one desired scenario to me.  However, it's still not a good fit for SO.  [Read THIS](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery it's pretty trivial.

In `page1.html` have such `<div>`:

```
<div id="pnlPage2Container"></div>
```

Then have this code in page1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oContainer = $("#pnlPage2Container");
    oContainer.hide();
    oContainer.load("page2.html", function() {
         oContainer.show();
    });
});
```

This should do the following:

1. Hide the container.
2. Load page2 contents into the container while it's hidden, so user won't see it loading.
3. Only when contents finished loading the container will become visible.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use AJAX and set the body's content to page 2, like so

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage2()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","page2.php",false); //setting asynchronous to false will stop more JS being executed until this is done
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="body" onload="loadPage2()">
<!-- Page 1 stuff -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you mean but is HTML5 prefetch any use?

- http://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch